# Prolog predicate to see if a square sequence converges to 1

Tags: prolog

Basically, the problem is the following:

Given a number N, we define the sequence where each number is the sum of the squares of the digits of the previous number. Give a predicate that given N checks if the sequence converges to 1. For instance, if N is 44 we got:
44, 32, 13, 10, 1.

So far, this is my approach:

```
splitRev(0,[]).
splitRev(N,[A|As]) :- N1 is floor(N/10), A is N mod 10, splitRev(N1,As).

sumSquares([],0).
sumSquares([X|L], N) :- X1 is X*X,
                        sumSquares(L,N1),
                        N is N1 + X1.

converge(1, L) :- write(L),nl.
converge(N, R) :- splitRev(N, L),
                  sumSquares(L,T),
                  \+member(T,R),
                  converge(T, [T|R]), !.
```

That works fine if the sequence converges, but it got caught in an infinite loop if it doesn't. I know what the problem is, but I'm not experienced with Prolog so I can't find a way to resolve it.
The expected output would be converge(2,[]) = false.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug a Prolog program composed of several predicates, it's useful to start with understanding its composite parts. Let's start with `splitRev/2`:

```
?- splitRev(2, Digits).
Digits = [2] ;
Digits = [2, 0] ;
Digits = [2, 0, 0] ;
Digits = [2, 0, 0, 0] .
```

This has a lot of redundant solutions. These are not incorrect per se, but they keep your program from making progress once it hits the case of a sum-of-squares that is already in your list `R`, i.e., the call `\+ member(T, R)` fails. In this case Prolog will backtrack to `splitRev(N, L)`, which will result in a new list `L` that is the same as before except that it has a zero at the end. Then you will compute a new sum of squares `T` which will be the same as the `T` value that failed before (since you just added zero), and the `\+ member(T, R)` call will fail again, ad infinitum.

To change this, it suffices to add a goal to `splitRev/2` to keep it from generating additional zeros for the number zero:

```
splitRev(0,[]).
splitRev(N,[A|As]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is floor(N/10),
    A is N mod 10,
    splitRev(N1,As).
```

This behaves better now:

```
?- splitRev(2, Digits).
Digits = [2] ;
false.
```

And now things fail as they should:

```
?- converge(2, []).
false.
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I thought it would be a problem with the converge predicate.